# Nested alternative validation required_without in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, validation, nested, laravel-5.8, validationrules

**here is my request**

```
{
    "formulations": [
        {
            "formulation_id": null,
            "formulation_custom_name": "test",
            "meal_time_id": null,
            "remark": "demo1"
        },
        {
            "formulation_id": 3,
            "formulation_custom_name": "asd",
            "meal_time_id": 2,
            "remark": "demo"
        }
    ]
}
```

**validation rule**

```
'formulations.*.formulation_id' => 'required_with:formulations.*.formulation_custom_name'
```

working properly for first object i.e formulation_id is required when formulation_custom_name is present

```
"errors": {
    "formulations.0.formulation_id": [
        "The formulations.0.formulation_id field is required when formulations.0.formulation custom name is present."
    ]
}
```

now my question is exactly opposite from above scenario i.e validate
formulation_custom_name required when formulation_id is null or not present
like

```
'formulations.*.formulation_id' => 'required_without:formulations.*.formulation_custom_name'
```

but this is **not working** for this request like this

```
{
    "formulations": [
        {
            "formulation_id": 6,
            "formulation_custom_name": "test",
            "meal_time_id": null,
            "remark": "demo1"
        }
}
```

*thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

`required_without` rule in Validator checks for field existence/presence and not for `empty` value or `null` value.

So you need `required_if` here, and use like below

```
'formulations.*.formulation_id' => 'required_if:formulations.*.formulation_custom_name,' // it will work for blank and null
```

Or if you need more complex condition then you can use `requiredIf` custom Rule

or if you need vice versa then write like below

```
'formulations.*.formulation_custom_name' => 'required_without:formulations.*.formulation_id'
```

[Document Link](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if)